# How to add density plot per component in PCA plot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, pca

I would like to know how add density to PCA plot .

This is my basic example which i would like to begin

```
x <- iris[1:4]
pc <- prcomp(x)
df <- cbind(pc$x[,1:2], iris[,5]) %>% as.data.frame()
df$PC1 <- as.numeric(df$PC1) / (pc$sdev[1] * sqrt(nrow(iris)))
df$PC2 <- as.numeric(df$PC2) / (pc$sdev[2] * sqrt(nrow(iris)))
df$V3 <- as.factor(df$V3)

#ggplot method
p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(PC1, PC2, colour = V3)) +
  geom_point(size = 3, aes(shape = V3)) +
  stat_ellipse(geom = "polygon", aes(fill = after_scale(alpha(colour, 0))),
               data = df[df$V3 == "1" | df$V3 == "2",], size = 1) 
p1
```

Now [image: PCA with density figure(E)]

I would like to add similar to my plot too how to do that? Any suggestion or help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the package `cowplot` by using `insert_*axis_grob` to insert two `geom_density` plots at the top x-axis and right y-axis. For the top x-axis density curve you can use the values of PC1 and for the right y-axis density curve you can use the values of PC2 and both color and fill them with V3. Make sure to specify the right `axis` for both graphs. Here is a reproducible example:

```r
library(cowplot)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
x <- iris[1:4]
pc <- prcomp(x)
df <- cbind(pc$x[,1:2], iris[,5]) %>% as.data.frame()
df$PC1 <- as.numeric(df$PC1) / (pc$sdev[1] * sqrt(nrow(iris)))
df$PC2 <- as.numeric(df$PC2) / (pc$sdev[2] * sqrt(nrow(iris)))
df$V3 <- as.factor(df$V3)

# plot
p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(PC1, PC2, colour = V3)) +
  geom_point(size = 3, aes(shape = V3)) +
  stat_ellipse(geom = "polygon", aes(fill = after_scale(alpha(colour, 0))),
               data = df[df$V3 == "1" | df$V3 == "2",], size = 1)

# Add density curves to y and x axis
xdens <- 
  axis_canvas(p1, axis = "x") + 
  geom_density(data = df, aes(x = PC1, fill = V3, colour = V3), alpha = 0.3)
ydens <-
  axis_canvas(p1, axis = "y", coord_flip = TRUE) + 
  geom_density(data = df, aes(x = PC2, fill = V3, colour = V3), alpha = 0.3) +
  coord_flip()
p1 %>%
  insert_xaxis_grob(xdens, grid::unit(1, "in"), position = "top") %>%
  insert_yaxis_grob(ydens, grid::unit(1, "in"), position = "right") %>%
  ggdraw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: thank you very much i will run it with my data and update you..in case

Comment: How do I label the species instead of 1,2,3 here in this case I mean the last column in the species name which I would like to reflect it in V3 where there are now 1,2 and 3

Comment: @PesKchan, you could change them by `labels` in `scale_colour_manual`. Check this [link](https://www.statology.org/ggplot-legend-labels/) with some examples.

Comment: can I provide external metadata? and use this to label instead of using a manual color..

Comment: @PesKchan, yes sure!

Comment: I would like to append to my question and would request you to have a look

Comment: @PesKchan, Maybe it is an idea to create a new question since it is about a new topic? This was about adding density curves to your plot.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73556666/adding-metadata-info-the-pca-in-r my new question